# Execute multiple CMD tasks and update asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, cmd

I'm implementing a C# application. I need to execute a program on multiple remote machines at the same time. To do so I'm using `PSExec` over a `CMD` with multithreading. Basically, for each machine, I start a thread that starts a `CMD` process. Depending on the result of the program executed remotely I'd like to either take an action or kill it if it takes more than x minutes (hope that makes sense).

The issue I've got is that I don't really know how to control for how long the process has been running other than using `WaitForExit` and, that doesn't really let me go multi-threading as it waits till the `CMD` call has finished.

I'm sure there must be a way of doing this but I cannot really figure it out. Could anyone please help me?

Here is my code (I'm new at c# coding so might not be the best code, feel free to correct any part of it you consider it is not right):

```
public async void BulkExecution()
{
    //Some code            
    foreach (string machine in Machines)
    {
        //more code to work out the CMDline and other duties.
        var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(r => ExecutePsexec((string)r, RunBeforeKillMsec), CMDLine);
        await result;
    }
    //More Code
}

private static void ExecutePsexec(string CMDline, int RunBeforeKillMsec)
{   
    Process compiler = new Process();
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "psexec.exe";
    compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = CMDline;
    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    compiler.Start();

    if (!compiler.WaitForExit(RunBeforeKillMsec))
    {
        ExecutePSKill(CMDline);
    }
    else
    {
        //Some Actions here
        Common.Log(LogFile, CMDline.Split(' ')[0] + " finished successfully");                
    }
}
```

Comment: You are telling it to wait: `await result;`. Remove that.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. The process is being hold by the `WaitForExit` rather than `await result`. The reason the `WaitForExit` is there is to check on the progress of the CMD and see if I have to Kill the process or consider it successfully finished. Do I make any sense?

Comment: ExecutePsexec runs in a separate task. All such tasks are independent. await result is what sequences them. Remove it.

Comment: yep, it works! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecutePsexec` runs in a separate task. All such tasks are independent. `await result;` is what sequences them. You need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Async void methods [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). You should change the signature of the `BulkExecution` method to return a `Task`, so that you can `await` it and handle any exceptions that may occur. Inside the method create a `Task` for each machine, and then await all tasks with the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method:

```
public async Task BulkExecution()
{
    //Some code            
    Task[] tasks = Machines.Select(machine =>
    {
        //more code to work out the CMDline and other duties.
        return Task.Run(r => ExecutePsexec(CMDLine, ExecutionTimeoutMsec));
    }).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    //More Code
}
```